# how to make an equation with two possible values inside only one bracket?

Tags: equations

I would like to make the following expression in Latex:

[image]

with an online editor I can do it by using the \begin{matrix} command, but when I want to put my formula into a Springer latex template using $ $ it only displays one line. I do not want to use the equation fields. How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can do it with LaTeX using the "matrix" environment (although "cases" would be better).  Could you show us how you're using matrix that isn't working?

Comment: The `cases` environment (requires `amsmath`} has a brace on only the left side.  It's pretty basic; see the `amsmath` user guide -- `texdoc amsmath`.  Also, you don't want the spacing of "accepts" and "rejects" to be that of strings of variables.  If you want them to be italic, enter them as `\mathit{...}`; if they should always be upright, `\textup{...}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the comments of the very good users which have help you with the comments, I add three short `LaTeX` codes that answer to your question.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[P=\begin{cases}
\text{accept}, & \text{if $x=1$}\\
\text{reject}, & \text{if $x=2$}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

If you prefer the same character as the `Cambria Math` image, I'll also attach another code that you need to compile with `LuaLaTeX`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}

\begin{document}
\[P=\begin{cases}
\text{accept}, & \text{if $x=1$}\\
\text{reject}, & \text{if $x=2$} 
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

From by comment of the excellent user @Bernard you can use also `dcases*` that works with `mathtools` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[P=\begin{dcases*}
\text{accept}, & \text{if $x=1$}\\
\text{reject}, & \text{if $x=2$} 
\end{dcases*}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) Maybe  `dcases*` would  yield a slightly simpler code?